# ClassNotFoundException when Using CronTrigger and MySQL to do scheduler

Tags: java, classpath, runtime-error, classnotfoundexception

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` when Using CronTrigger and MySQL to do scheduler in Java

I am currently developing a project that require scheduler to download data from MySQL database from a server and put it into a text file stored in a fixed directory. I am using CronTrigger and scheduler to accomplish this task and my project will be reside in Tomcat version 6.0/webapps directory. However, i encountered this problem when i run my program.

```
Jul 5, 2013 3:10:00 PM org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport triggerFired
SEVERE: Error retrieving job, setting trigger state to ERROR.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job because a required class was not found: bgoc.dwgScheduler.dwg_QuartzAutoDownloadJob [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bgoc.dwgScheduler.dwg_QuartzAutoDownloadJob]**<br>

at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1328)<br>
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggerFired(JobStoreSupport.java:2789)<br>
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$37.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2757)<br>
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3662)<br>
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggerFired(JobStoreSupport.java:2751)<br>
at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:313)<br>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bgoc.dwgScheduler.dwg_QuartzAutoDownloadJob <br>
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)<br>
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)<br>
at org.quartz.simpl.InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.loadClass(InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.java:74)<br>
at org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper.loadClass(CascadingClassLoadHelper.java:118)<br>
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectJobDetail(StdJDBCDelegate.java:897)<br>
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1316)<br>
```

I am sure that my java code is not the problem because this error does not occur all the time. However, it has a 30% occurance rate which is quite high. However, i am not sure whether my quartz file is written correctly. Below is the quartz file written.

### Configure Main Scheduler Properties ##

> org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler 
>   org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = one

### Configure ThreadPool

> org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool 
>   org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5 
>   org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 4

### Configure JobStore

> org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 5000 
>   org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX 
>   org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate 
>   org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS 
>   org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

### Configure Datasources

> org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
>   org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/QRTZ_BIS 
>   org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = root 
>   org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = password 
>   org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections 5

Can anyone help me with this problem? If you would like to have more information please do post, I will provide it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classloader complains about class `bgoc.dwgScheduler.dwg_QuartzAutoDownloadJob` missing.

Is this class yours? 
Have you checked if this class is on the classpath ?

Maybe this class is not necessary, but some other class or configuration may be importing it.

Comment: Yes, bgoc.dwgScheduler.dwg_QuartzAutoDownloadJob is my class.         I am sure it is on my classpath because sometimes it does not give the error and produce the result i wanted. The class is necessary because it is where i run all my function and produce the results

Comment: Ok, I see... Quartz stores jobs in the database with Java class information. The problem occurs if the Java code changes and the class information in the database refer to deleted and/or renamed classes. Maybe your class that has been renamed or removed and this class name has been persisted on a table used by quartz. Try to replace the persisted name by the correct one or try to clear the table on which job's names are persisted.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i will try to clear the quartz table and see whether the problem persist.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same situation. This was caused because I removed a previously used job, during a version release. I did not count for a few triggers (not cron, but simple delayed ones) staying in the DB. Those tried to execute but failed because their job was removed already.

What I ended up doing is putting the job back with empty execute method body (logging the fact it was called).

This way, after deploying the version with the empty method, the triggers can fire with no problem, quartz won't whine about that.
In the next version you can then remove the empty job too.

Deleting manually from the quartz tables is risky and generally not advisable. You probably don't know what row(s) belong to job triggers/jobs.