# Trigger specific Quartz jobs

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am using `Quartz` to schedule jobs and use a console application to execute all the jobs.

I currently have 2 console applications which refer to the same set of Quartz tables viz. QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS, QRTZ_TRIGGERS etc.

Due to this, when I execute ConsoleApp1 which doesn't have jobs (created in ConsoleApp2), I get the following error:

```
XYZ job: Couldn't retrieve job because a required type was not found: Could not load type 'XYZ-Job, XYZ.Job' ---> Quartz.JobPersistenceException:
```

I have checked the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480452/classnotfoundexception-when-using-crontrigger-and-mysql-to-do-scheduler).

Obvious solution is to create separate Quartz table-sets for each console application. That way, I won't get any load type errors.

My question is, in such a scenario, is there a way to get only particular jobs (based on some match), so that I don't need to create 2 table sets.

In the below code, I was thinking if I get all the job names, I will disable the triggers for ConsoleApp2. But then, ConsoleApp2 won't have any jobs to run! (this is because, the tables are same)

Please let me know if there is a better solution.

```
        protected async void StartScheduler1()
        {
                ISchedulerFactory schedFact = container.ResolveType<ISchedulerFactory>();
                var schedTask = schedFact.GetScheduler();

                schedTask.Wait();
                scheduler = schedTask.Result;

            var jobs = new List<JobKey>();
            foreach (var group in scheduler.GetJobGroupNames().Result)
            {
                var groupMatcher = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupContains(@group);
                foreach (var jobKey in scheduler.GetJobKeys(groupMatcher).Result)
                {
                    jobs.Add(jobKey);
                }
            }

            scheduler.Start().Wait();
        }
```

Comment: You can cluster your quartz scheduler and write jobs which are application agnostic in that case you don't need two sets of table.Or use different quartz.conf files to initialize each scheduler in this way you can store in the same tables but the scheduler name and group will be different,but you need to maintain separate confs

Comment: I do have separate config files, but how will that help? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: change the scheduler name and assign separate names in both the configuration files  in this way the job entries and corresponding triggers are saved under that job schedular and group name and quartz will query the table based on them.So,you can use the same tables and can achieve the separation of data.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution. There is a column called `Sched_Name` in Quartz tables. This column is used by Quartz scheduler to get job details.
Using this column, we can have numerous different groups in the same Quartz tables. There is no need create separate Quartz table-sets.
For e.g.

`SELECT * FROM QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'CESA'`

`SELECT * FROM QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'CESB'`